# Clear token from session from filter in Play Framework (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework

Is it possible to flash whole session or some key in it inside filter? 
I want store some token in session which will bind user from DB to session and create filter which will check if token id Db equal to token in session. If not - it should invalidate the session. Can it be done or may be I need to do it differently? I have access to requestHeader object in filter. I thought of a way to make a copy of it with modified session in a filter. Or should I move this logic to Controller?

Answer (score -2):

Check out [Reading a Session value](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSessionFlash#Reading-a-Session-value) and [Discarding the whole session](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSessionFlash#Discarding-the-whole-session).

Comment: I've read this. But this Ok("Bye").withNewSession is usable only in controllers. Do you mean clearing of session is not available in filter?